# embeddings of Khalimsky line into $\mathbb{R}$ matching with cubical complex digital geometry

Tags: geometry, discrete-geometry

The Khalimsky line can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}$ as follows [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI8Wy.png):

> Let us identify with each even integer $m$ the closed, real interval $[m − 1/2,m + 1/2]$ and with each odd integer $n$ the open interval $]n − 1/2, n + 1/2[$. These intervals form
> a partition of the Euclidean line $\mathbb{R}$ and we may consider the quotient space.

I am interested in a different embedding, with even integers $n$ to represent $]n÷2 - 1/2, n÷2 + 1/2[$ and odd integers $m$ to represent $m/2$ (i.e. $[m/2, m/2]$).

That definition would align with a uniform cubical complex:
[image: cubical complex illustration]

Is there a valid connection between Khalimsky spaces and uniform cubical complexes? I am surprised not to find these two keywords coexisting, except perhaps in the source code of [DGtal](https://github.com/DGtal-team/DGtal/search?q=khalismky).

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI8Wy.png): [Digital Geometry and Khalimsky Spaces, dissertation by Erik Melin](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:171330/FULLTEXT01.pdf)

[2]: [abstract cell complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_cell_complex)

[3]: [a software library implementing representation of cubical complex](https://gudhi.inria.fr/python/latest/cubical_complex_user.html#)

[4]: [interactive webpage depicting the embedding I want, slider should be infinitesimally to the left](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/edges/#diagram-corner-coordinates)

[5]: [Geometry of Locally Finite Spaces](http://www.geometry.kovalevsky.de/)